# How to check if component has a child node of <template></template>?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-components

MyComponent for example:

```
<div [my-component]="'text'"></div>
```

In code I have `this.viewContainerRef` which is the node itself (`<div>`).

But the user may want to add its template to `myComponent`, so he will do this:

```
<div [my-component]="'text'">
   <template>
   ...
   </template>
</div>
```

My question is how in code I can check if there is a `<template>` node and use/read its innerHTML?

Comment: Are you using Angular 4?

Comment: angular 2, but I may update soon

Comment: In Angular 2 there won't ever be a `<template>` element in the DOM. In Angular 4 `<template>` is renamed to `<ng-template>` to free `<template>` to be added to the DOM. I'm not sure about Angular4, because using `<template>` causes a deprecation warning. Not sure if `<template>` will only be freed in Angular5 or if it already is (haven't tried myself) - just check the DOM if the element is actually there.

Comment: hmm... why not? If I need some html that will not be visible to the user, but I do want to use it somewhere, for example a popup that will open...

Comment: `<template>` is just translated to JavaScript when you build your application and never actually becomes a DOM element and only handled internally by Angular. This is why they changed it to `<ng-template>` because `<template>` is a normal HTML element and for example sometimes required when you want to use Polymer with Angular (just one example I run into).

Comment: I can only see in dom <!--template bindings={}-->

Comment: That's expected. There is no `<template>` element and in Angular2 there is no way to make Angular to add one. You can add one using direct DOM manipulation like `<div [innerHTML]="someHtml | safeHtml"></div>` with `someHtml = '<template>...</template>`. This way you work around Angular. (`safeHtml` is a sanitizer pipe I showed in one of my answers)

Comment: So how you insert html markup that you want to give the user to create? popup, tooltip, ... components that sometimes you want inside of them some html the user will write

Comment: You can use `<template>` or (`<ng-template>` in Angular4) and then use `ngTemplateOutlet` or `ngForTemplate` (or `createInnerView` not sure this is the correct name)` to stamp the template. This only works if your popup, tooltip, ... components are Angular components and expect to get a template passed. Still the `<template>` tag won't ever be added to the DOM, you can still access it by using `@ViewChild(TemplateRef) template:TemplateRef;` in `MyComponent`, because Angular handles this interanally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ContentChild(TemplateRef) and after that render when template is defined and when it is just html. Here is an example. This is for Angular 2. For Angular 4 '*ngIf;else Block' can be used.

```
  @Component({
    selector: '[my-component]',
    template: `
      my-component with input {{v}}
      <ng-container *ngIf="tpl">
        Template block:
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngIf="!tpl">
        No Template block: <ng-content></ng-content>
      </ng-container>
    `
  })
  export class MyComponent {
    @Input('my-component') v : string;
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) public tpl: TemplateRef;
  }
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <div [my-component]="'text'">
          <template><pre>hi there</pre></template>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div [my-component]="'text1'">
          aaa
        </div>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    constructor() {
    }
  }
```

Comment: works and simple to understand and also to use, from a user perspective that is going to use this component. Thank you!